Can’t Directly Open Whatsapp Group Invite Link On Safari Browser
I can't open group invite links from either whatsapp or telegram directly in html.

I tried this html anchor tag:
<a href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></a>
And this javascript code:
window.location.href="https://chat.whatsapp.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Does anyone know how to get this to work? Setting window.location.href used to work for me. I would appreciate anyone who can provide a solution.
